# Combining 20000 daily csv files from a folder and then importing to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, tableau-api

I have csv files that contains sales data (quantity, product code) of a store. There are 20000 csv files of these that are added daily and consists of 1000 rows. I want to combine these csv files and then import them into an SQL table. (all the csv files have the same columns)

I have 2 questions:

1. What are the ways to achieve this? I want to do this daily automatically.
2. Should I clean my data before importing them to an SQL table? Or after? And how can I do that (clean data)? I've tried tableau prep to clean them (without combining the csv files) and it took too long.

Later on the data on the SQL table will be used to make visualization on Tableau Desktop to be used daily, hence why the data needs to be updated/appended with new data daily.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, we can't really answer general questions like how to clean your data unless you give us a lot more information, and even then it is a complex topic which not everyone can agree on. Also, what language are you looking to implement this in?

Comment: Each CSV file contains the sales data (quantity, product code) of a store. So the data is basically sales of 20000 stores daily. So far, I've tried tableau prep to join and use all the csv files to clean them, but it took too long, so I wanted to try combine the CSV files first and put the combined data into SQL so I can use the SQL table on tableau prep. As to what language I'm looking to implement this, I don't really know where to start since this is my first time working with data. In the past I've only used C# to develop web apps.

Comment: 2 questions: How do you want to combine the csvs and what are you trying to clean? --Off the top of my head I would suggest using Python with pandas dataframes, because pandas is made for this kind of thing, but unless you have a couple days to kind of learn what you need to do that's not super helpful advice. I guess you could use C# if you know it better, but it's not going to be as good at manipulating data and I'm no expert on C# so I can't give any meaningful advice in that regard

Comment: I think I might try python and pandas, should I just do an iteration through each file and add them to SQL, or should I combine the csv files first?

Comment: Combine all the files first. If the files don’t have headers then this is simple to do using DOS/Powershell/Linux commands - depending on your OS. Even if they do have headers then this is still achievable, though more complicated. A quick Google will give lots of examples about how to do this